# Post notice for duplicating question does not show the duplicated question

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

Question: [Why do we still use JavaScript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/90057/192731)
[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a legacy issue caused by the old way of handling duplicates versus the new way. I resolved it by reopening and voting to close.

Comment: just wonder what is that issue?

Comment: @Ooker I'd have to find the Meta post, but it's several years old at this point. Just a change in how linked duplicates were recorded over the years. They used to be generated text in the body of the post, but were since changed to appear in the close message. Reopening, removing the old auto-generated content in the body, and closing with the question as a duplicate makes it look right and be useful to future readers.